# Cannot resolve ResponseEntity in SpringMVC using JpaRepository

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

This is my Controller:

```
package com.hodor.booking.controller;

import com.hodor.booking.jpa.domain.Vehicle;
import com.hodor.booking.service.VehicleService;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api;
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/vehicles")
@Api(value = "vehicles", description = "Vehicle resource endpoint")

public class VehicleController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VehicleController.class);

    @Autowired
    private VehicleService vehicleService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Vehicle> index() {
        log.debug("Getting all vehicles");
        return vehicleService.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")

    @ResponseBody
    public Vehicle setVehicle(@RequestBody Vehicle vehicle) {
        log.debug("Inserting vehicle");

        if (vehicle.getLicensePlate() == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }

        return vehicleService.saveVehicle(vehicle);
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve in above If-Guard is that, in case the vehicle Object does not have the LicensePlate Member, send back an according HTTP Status Header CONFLICT or something.

I am coming from a Node and Express background and I am used to set my header, send the response and be done with it. However in this case (JPA) it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to take advantage of Spring's validation support to declarative add validation of your POJOs. Basically, you add annotations to your `Vehicle` class like:

```
public class Vehicle {
    @NotNull
    private LicensePlate licensePlate;

    // getters, setters
}
```

And you add a `@Valid` annotation to your controller method:

```
@ResponseBody
public Vehicle setVehicle(@RequestBody @Valid Vehicle vehicle) {
    log.debug("Inserting vehicle");
    return vehicleService.saveVehicle(vehicle);
}
```

If the validation fails, Spring will return a 400 response.

Make sure that you have JSR-303/JSR-349 Bean Validation implementation such as the Hibernate Validator (it can be used without Hibernate's ORM support) on your classpath.

More information can be found in the [validation chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation) of the Spring reference docs.

Comment: I am using now the `@NotNull` annotation from this class "javax.validation.constraints.NotNull". Returns a 500 Server Error if null is true, Fair EnoughAs a bonus, is there an annotation like this as well? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Future.html. Think I found it: `@Future` annotation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624532/where-is-implementation-of-future-defined

Answer (score 1):

What version of Spring MVC are you using?  From another post [How to respond with HTTP 400 error in a Spring MVC @ResponseBody method returning String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232833/how-to-respond-with-http-400-error-in-a-spring-mvc-responsebody-method-returnin).  It states that Spring MVC 4.1 and later using different syntax.